# What is use of "$" and "&" sign in Install Exec Condition in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield, custom-action

In many of the Custom Actions I saw the "$" and "&" sign in Install Exec condition of a Custom Action in InstallShield. I did not get the significance of these signs.
Here are some examples of such conditions

```
(&Server=2 Or &Client=2)  
$capicom.dll=3
```

So can someone tell me the use of these signs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are standard Windows Installer Conditional operators.
Everything is explained here: [Conditional Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx)